# Pictures don't show up in Facebook if I use Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, facebook, photo

A few days ago my browser(Firefox) has stopped loading images when using Facebook.com . I tried `Google-chrome` and it turned out that photos don't load up there too.

However, The pictures show up without any problem when I use Firefox in `Windows` although Firefox have the exact same version as in the one in Linux.

**The steps I have tried so far are:**

- Remove all cookies , cache and reset to the default settings
- Removed `.mozilla` folder and set it manually but the problem becomes big now no photo in facebook appear

---

**Here is photo that shows the problem:**

[image]

**While images show up fine in other websites:**

[image]

So as you can see the problem is only in Linux  whether it is `Firefox` or `google-chrome`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ? 10.04 ?

Comment: Check out this Solution, http://askubuntu.com/questions/125737/facebook-pictures-not-showing-up?rq=1

Comment: Have you tired Chromium ?

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04.2 and firefox 20

and yes i tried google chrome and same problem is there 

I will try your solution my brother suhaib and see what will happened

Comment: This solution fixed my problem.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/125737/facebook-pictures-not-showing-up/189325#189325?newreg=ed1020558836469e80781602aa604825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Account Settings/Security Settings/Secure Browsing and uncheck this option: "Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) when possible". Then save changes and restart Facebook. It worked for me and I had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and searched for an answer online.  I tried the solution of changing browser settings on facebook, no luck there.  I tried updating firefox only to find it was updated, and then clicked 'return firefox to original settings'.  Success! Yes, I had to re-set some things, but it fixed the problem of pics not downloading.